# Untokenized field in Lucene search

Tags: lucene

I have stored a field in index file which is untokenized. When I try to get that field value from the index file I'm not able to do get it.

Note: I have another one untokenized field, there I'm able to get that value, the data stored in this field are not having any white spaces among this.

Example: `(smith,david,walter,john)...` But the one I'm asking is having white spaces among it. Example: `(david smith,mark john,bill man)...`

I don't think this might be the reason.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please make the example more descriptive, as in: The value stored in the index is: AAAAAAA, The value in the query is: BBBBBB. From the current phrasing of your question, the problem seems to be exactly having an untokenized field.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that tokenization or lack of it has to be done both while indexing and searching.
Did you try using a keywordTokenizer in the search side?

Comment: No... Can you please explain where and how to use keywordTokenizer with an example??
Thanks in advance..